# API REST mainly accesed by IoT Cloud/Edge platforms (Azure, Mozilla IoT, Google Cloud...)

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm creating an app that have an API REST that is going to be mainly accessed by devices and other apps hosted in IoT Cloud/Edge Platforms. My question is: Do I need to prepare something special or different to a regular API REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is just REST, no matter who calls it. You should think as always about authentication, and other aspects of security such encryption of sensitive data / HTTPS, if relevant, data size and proper data encoding. Hope this answers the question.